# How to create a new instance from a class object in Python

Tags: python, oop

I need to dynamically create an instance of a class in Python. Basically I am using the load_module and inspect module to import and load the class into a class object, but I can't figure out how to create an instance of this class object.

Comment: What? `instance = Class()` ...

Comment: I am supposing you want ot dynamically createe a new class. Not an object of a given class.

Comment: new instance means a new object with its own space in memory. most languages use a 'new' keyword so that it is explicit that the object is new and that the new instance's (object's) properties are not referenced/shared with another instance.

Comment: As Python don't use a "new" keyword, I updated my answer bellow with a full explanation of the class instatiation mechanism.

Answer (score 178):

I figured out the answer to the question I had that brought me to this page.  Since no one has actually suggested the answer to my question, I thought I'd post it.

```
class k:
  pass

a = k()
k2 = a.__class__
a2 = k2()
```

At this point, a and a2 are both instances of the same class (class k).

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Works and it is simple.

Comment: Note you can also pass parameters to the constructor, if the __init__ accepts them
 `a3 = k2(7)`

Comment: What's the difference between `k2 = a.__class__` and `k2 = k` ?

Comment: `k2` is the object type, in this case de type of `a` (`a.__class`), `k2()` create a new instance of object of that type independant of `a`. `k2 = k` would simply create a new reference to the same instance.

Comment: you can also get the `class` object with `k2 = type(a)` and then call the class object `a2 = k2()`. It's fundamentally the same but you don't have to litter your code with those ugly double-underscores … might be more portable too

Answer (score 26):

Just call the "type" built in using three parameters, like this:

```
ClassName = type("ClassName", (Base1, Base2,...), classdictionary)
```

**update**
as stated in the comment bellow this is not the answer to this question at all. I will keep it undeleted, since there are hints some people  get here  trying to dynamically create classes - which is what the line above does.

To create an object of a class one has a reference too, as put in the accepted answer, one just have to call the class:

```
instance = ClassObject()
```

The mechanism for instantiation is thus:

Python does not use the `new` keyword some languages use - instead its data model explains the mechanism used to create an instance of a class when it is called with the same syntax as any other callable:

Its class' `__call__` method is invoked (in the case of a class, its class is the "metaclass" - which is usually the built-in `type`). The normal behavior of this call is to invoke the (pseudo) static `__new__` method on the class being instantiated, followed by its `__init__`. The `__new__` method is responsible for allocating memory and such, and normally is done by the `__new__` of `object` which is the class hierarchy root.

So calling `ClassObject()` invokes `ClassObject.__class__.call()` (which normally will be `type.__call__`) this `__call__` method will receive ClassObject itself as the first parameter - a Pure Python implementation would be like this: (the cPython version is, of course, done in C, and with lots of extra code for cornercases and optimizations)

```
class type:
    ...
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
          constructor = getattr(cls, "__new__")
          instance = constructor(cls) if constructor is object.__new__ else constructor(cls, *args, **kw)
          instance.__init__(cls, *args, **kw)
          return instance
```

(I don't recall seeing on the docs the exact justification (or mechanism) for suppressing extra parameters to the root `__new__` and passing it to other classes - but it is what happens "in real life" - if `object.__new__` is called with any extra parameters it raises a type error - however, any custom implementation of a `__new__` will get the extra parameters normally)

Comment: Didn't the OP want to create an instance, not a class?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a module with a class you want to import, you can do it like this.

```
module = __import__(filename)
instance = module.MyClass()
```

If you do not know what the class is named, you can iterate through the classes available from a module.

```
import inspect
module = __import__(filename)
for c in module.__dict__.values():
    if inspect.isclass(c):
        # You may need do some additional checking to ensure 
        # it's the class you want
        instance = c()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have some class object, you can instantiate it by just calling it (with parenthesis).

```
class MyClass: pass        
some_class = MyClass    
some_instance = some_class() # -> instance of MyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the neat way would be using `type`. Here is an example:

```py
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, s):
...       self.s = s
... 
>>> a = Foo("hello")
>>> a.s
'hello'
>>> b = type(a)("world")
>>> b.s
'world'
>>> assert isinstance(a, Foo)
>>> assert isinstance(b, Foo)
```

`b` is an instance which has the same type as `a`.